# Qt - draw pixmap (.png file) with QPainter from resources

Tags: qt, resources, draw, qpainter, qpixmap

I have some problems with drawing image on QWidget with QPainter from resources. I'm sure I'm missing something but I really dont know what. If I use absolute path, it works fine.

So my question is: what should I do if I want to draw .png file from resources with QPainter? (What am I missing?)

Here is my simple test code:

Widget.h:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>

class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

Widget.cpp:

```
#include "Widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent) { }

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {

    QPainter painter(this);

    QPixmap pixmap1("C:/Qt/Projects/pixmapTest/image.png");
    QPixmap pixmap2(":/img/image.png");
    QPixmap pixmap3("qrc:/img/image.png");


    painter.drawPixmap(10,10,50,50, pixmap1);  // this works
    painter.drawPixmap(10,70,50,50, pixmap2); // this not
    painter.drawPixmap(10,130,50,50, pixmap3); // this neither
}
```

img.qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/img">
        <file>image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-04-01T17:11:38
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = pixmapTest
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        Widget.cpp

HEADERS  += Widget.h

FORMS    +=

RESOURCES += \
    img.qrc
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I expected, it was really stupid problem. All i had to do was clean project, run qmake and build... Thanks to svlasov :)

Edit:
So in order to draw .png file with QPainter and QPixmap from resources, you have to:
add your picture to resources

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/img">
        <file>image.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

then you can use relative path to your file in resources like here (format is ":/prefix/you/created/file.something" or you can use alias - here is [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html))

```
QPixmap pixmap2(":/img/image.png");
```

then draw it

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawPixmap(10,70,50,50, pixmap2);
```

and clean and build project and it will work :)